# Creating a function and calling it in main program

Tags: c, function, calculator, avr, atmega

I have a case in AVR programming

```
case (0xe7): keyPressed=".";
```

during this I want to call a pre-defined function

```
switch (keyCode)               //generating key characetr to display on LCD
{

case (0xee): keyPressed="1";
            b=1;
            a=a*10+b; 
            i=i++;
            break;
case (0xed): keyPressed="4";
            b=4;
            a=a*10+b; 
            i=i++;
            break;
case (0xeb): keyPressed="7";
            b=7;
            a=a*10+b; 
            i=i++;
            break;
case (0xde): keyPressed="2";
            b=2;
            a=a*10+b; 
            i=i++;
            break;
case (0xdd): keyPressed="5";
            b=5;
            a=a*10+b; 
            i=i++;
            break;
case (0xdb): keyPressed="8";
            b=8;
            a=a*10+b; 
            i=i++;
            break;
case (0xd7): keyPressed="0";
            b=0;
            a=a*10+b; 
            i=i++;
            break;
case (0xbe): keyPressed="3";
            b=3;
            a=a*10+b; 
            i=i++;
            break;
case (0xbd): keyPressed="6";
            b=6;
            a=a*10+b; 
            i=i++;
            break;
case (0xbb): keyPressed="9";
            b=9;
            a=a*10+b; 
            i=i++;
            break;
}
```

How do I make the function?? and call it during my case in the main program?
Please guide me I am new to all this...
Help me out please..

Comment: Don't do `i = i++`, its behavior is undefined.

Comment: I actually want the whole number "a" to be stored as an integer and later on divide it by 10^i to get it in decimal form.. i represents total number of times keys are pressed.. Please guide me the correct way?

Comment: `i++;` is equivalent to `i = i+1;` Joachim is right

Comment: Also, there's no point in having parenthesis around the `case` label expressions. Just `case 0xe7:` and so on is a little cleaner.

Comment: @ndj, `i++` differs from `i=i+1` in the returned value. `i=i++` is UB, while `i=i=i+1` is (I think) valid.

Comment: @MohitGoyal Please directly say what you want `with an example` so that it is easily understandable and quickly answerable.

Comment: @ugoren, you're absolutely right, the semicolon are added for this very reason, to express that the whole lines are equivalent (not the expression statement only)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, In your case When ever you press key from avr you get Keycode value for example when you press 1 you get address 1 ,when you press 2 you will get address 2,when you press 3 you will get address 3 and so on when you press 9 you will get address 9.and when you press . you will get address 10.
but in c you did not get input like that.used scanf to read from stdin. and repeated loop untill pressing '.'

each keypress you ae holding keypressed and adding that key to the sequenceof keyspressed and no of times keyspressed.

```
b=whichkeypressed;
a=a*10+b;
i++;
```

if you press **3,2,1**, and . then **a=321 ,b=1 ,i=3**

After pressing '.'
you are calling predifined function there you are calculating

```
c=pow(10,i); 
i=3 => c=1000
and d=a/c;
a=321 ,c=1000
d=0.321
```

The code which performs operation as above is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int a,b,i;
double  c,d;


void function()
{
c= pow(10,i);
d=a/c;
}


main()
{

int keyCode;
char keyPressed;

while(1)
{
printf("Enter Keycode: ");
scanf("%d",&keyCode);

switch (keyCode)               //generating key characetr to display on LCD
{

case 1: keyPressed='1';
            b=1;
            a=a*10+b;
            i++;
            break;
case 4: keyPressed='4';
            b=4;
            a=a*10+b;
            i++;
            break;
case 7: keyPressed='7';
            b=7;
            a=a*10+b;
            i++;
            break;
case 2: keyPressed='2';
            b=2;
            a=a*10+b;
            i++;
            break;
case 5: keyPressed='5';
            b=5;
            a=a*10+b;
            i++;
            break;
case 8: keyPressed='8';
            b=8;
            a=a*10+b;
            i++;
            break;
case 0: keyPressed='0';
            b=0;
            a=a*10+b;
            i++;
            break;
case 3: keyPressed='3';
            b=3;
            a=a*10+b;
            i++;
            break;
case 6: keyPressed='6';
            b=6;
            a=a*10+b;
            i++;
            break;
case 9: keyPressed='9';
            b=9;
            a=a*10+b;
            i++;
            break;

case 10: keyPressed='.';
             printf("No of Times Keys Pressed are = %d\n",i);

             function();
                printf("sequence of keys pressed=%d \nlast key pressed=%d\npower value of Keys=%lf\n The decimal valueof given sequence of keys=%6.10lf\n",a,b,c,d);   //use c and d with the values what you required.

                                break;

        }

        if (keyPressed=='.')
        break;

        }
getchar();
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Enter Keycode: 1
Enter Keycode: 2
Enter Keycode: 3
Enter Keycode: 4
Enter Keycode: 5
Enter Keycode: 6
Enter Keycode: 7
Enter Keycode: 8
Enter Keycode: 9
Enter Keycode: 10
No of Times Keys Pressed are = 9
sequence of keys pressed=123456789
last key pressed=9
power value of Keys=1000000000.000000
The decimal valueof given sequence of keys=0.1234567890
```

For avr you need to make some required changes,at case addresses and next keypressed statement and some additional.

Comment: sorry but I am not able to get the desired result :/

Comment: @MohitGoyal edited the answer.if My assumption is correct then you would get something which is required from this.